# Install step with folder and java

Tags: java, github, directory, repository

From this [repository](https://github.com/collab-uniba/Personality-Recognition-in-SD)

I try to run this step

```
./PersonalityRecognizer -i ../output_dir -d -t 2 -a ../mairesse_Apache.arff
```

but I receive this error

```
$ ./PersonalityRecognizer -i ../output_dir -d -t 2 -a ../mairesse_Apache.arff
./PersonalityRecognizer: line 15: ../../apps/jdk1.5.0_05/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

How can I proceed? Which file or directory is not?

Into the instructions they refer this:

> Open the file PersonalityRecognizer (or PersonalityRecognizer.bat if
>   you're using Windows) and edit the variable JDK_PATH with the full
>   path to the root of your Java installation.

So here is the file which I made the change:

```
@echo off
rem WINDOWS LAUNCH SCRIPT

rem ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES TO MODIFY

set JDK_PATH="C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath"
set WEKA="H:\apps\weka-3-4\weka.jar"

rem ----------------------------------

set COMMONS_CLI="lib\commons-cli-1.0.jar"
set JMRC="lib\jmrc.jar"

set LIBS=%WEKA%;%COMMONS_CLI%;%JMRC%;%CD%;bin\

%JDK_PATH%\bin\java -Xmx512m -classpath %LIBS% recognizer.PersonalityRecognizer %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

However if I run this in cmd to check for java I receive this one:

```
C:\Users\Nathalie>which java
/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath/java
```

What can I do?

Comment: Why don't you create an issue there? The file/dir not found is explicitly named as `../../apps/jdk1.5.0_05/bin/java`. If that's somehow related to your PC, then you should fix the path and update your JDK, if not, then you again need to raise an issue on that github repo.

Comment: @Tom I made an update in the question in order to show the problem I believe from my side

Comment: `javapath` doesn't point "to the root of your Java installation" as the description says it needs. It only links to `java.exe`, `javaw.exe` and `javaws.exe`. You should look for the actual install dir of Java and use that instead. It could for example be `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-(version)`.

Comment: @Tom I used this `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151` but again the same problem I think

Comment: Exact same error message (same path mentioned there)? If yes, then you need to raise the issue on github. It still might be a local issue with your PC, but to analyze that one needs to check how the app access and uses your JDK_PATH. They can do that better.

Comment: @Tom I tried a different way. Execute this command using cmd `./PersonalityRecognizer -i ../output_dir -d -t 2 -a ../mairesse_Apache.arff` but it doesn't recognize .